# Implement Display, Edit and New forms in spfx web part using reactjs

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, reactjs

I have 3 buttons on spfx web part 'Display','Edit' and 'New'.
When I click on these buttons, respective form should open with text boxes and data from sharepoint (online) list.
  I want to use Reactjs with VS Code.
How can I implement this requirement?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you wish to implement SharePoint CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) using react js in Visual Studio Code. Is it so?

Comment: yes, with document library

Answer (score 1):

You simply add the link to the list forms in the buttons. For example the new form

```
<PrimaryButton href="/serverelativeURL/Lists/LISTNAME/NewForm.aspx" >New</PrimaryButton>
```

It should open the form. If you want to redirect after that, add the ?Source parameter:

`/serverelativeURL/Lists/LISTNAME/NewForm.aspx?Source=/serverrelativeURL/yourspfxwebpartpage`

Comment: I tried below code, but throwing 404 error.                   
<PrimaryButton href="/serverelativeURL/Lists/LISTNAME/NewForm.aspx" >New</PrimaryButton>

Comment: You have to add your server relative ulr and your list name...

Comment: I used proper URLS, list names, DispForm/EditForm is working, but NewForm.aspx throwing 404

Comment: Go to your list and open create a new item. Check the url in the browser and use it ;-)

Comment: Thanks Oskar, how do I get 'yourspfxwebpartpage'? The form is opening in sharepoint online

Comment: Sorry I should have written more. This is the WebPage page on which your spfx solution is running. If you want to redirect after the submit back to your page you simple paste the url from your page as source parameter.

Comment: I appended the source parameter like below, but didn't work.                                                                                               ?Source=https://tenantURL/sites/devsite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

Comment: How can if u have to avoid the page post back?